# Basic IP-Safelist implementation for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, security, asp.net-web-api

I have a cloud software that has a basic JWT Auth (long client tokens). We want to add an additional security mechanism that only allows certain IP numbers to access a specific account. Since the IP number might change at any time at the client, my suggestion is that we run a local Windows service that keeps pushing the client IP number and add its to the safe list.

So every minute my local Windows service calls my Cloud Server asking "What is my IP?" Cloud server returns the IP (RemoteIpAddress as code below), and the service then creates a POST request back to the cloud server to add the IP number to the safe list.

Then when the real client (typically a mobile device, always in the same network as the local windows service), in my ASP.NET Core controller I compare the IP number with the safe list and grants or decline access.

For both comparing and fetching the IP number I am thinking to use the property:

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress
```

Is there some obvious flaw in this mechanism or does this sound like a good idea? I understand if the credentials (and client secrets) of the Windows Service gets compromised a malicious actor could add their own IP to the safe list but is there any other flaws in this scheme? For instance can that property be spoofed?

Comment: You can get remote IP and then can compare with your whitelist. Based on your whitelist you can decide whether you would allow request or decline. You can [`get more details in official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/ip-safelist?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Hi, @MdFaridUddinKiron can you provide an example on how to do this safely? Especially with regards to that it should not be possible to spoof the IP-Address?